# Python: Do I need to install Tensorflow and Pytorch in two different conda environments?

Tags: installation, anaconda, cuda, dependencies

***Intro:***

I do not know whether I should install pytorch and tensorflow in separated environments if I want to install both.

For conda tensorflow, I find at https://machinelearningspace.com/installing-tensorflow-2-0-in-anaconda-environment/ the recommendation (example)

```
conda create -n test python=3.7
```

and at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357038/how-do-i-install-tensorflow-2-2-in-windows, the answer of someone who had installed the latest version with pip (crashing the conda dependencies) states:

> ONE IMPORTANT THING: for now, at least in my case, there is a major
> problem with the GPU version. The old one recognises my GPU with no
> issues, while the latest doesn't see it for some reason. I advise you
> to create, just in case, a new env so you won't need to reinstall
> everything later on.

For conda pytorch, an env seems to be recommended as well (examples):

```
conda create --name test
```

at https://medium.com/@bryant.kou/how-to-install-pytorch-on-windows-step-by-step-cc4d004adb2a or

```
conda create -n pytorch_env
```

at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951846/installing-pytorch-via-conda.

It might be plausible due to their possibly different dependencies (for example, using different versions of cudatoolkit) that they should be in different environments. But I do not want to install all of the other packages twice in each environment then.

The environments are recommended for each project you set up. You should leave the base environment as it is and only install in the project environment. And then, what if you need both Tensorflow and Pytorch in one project, so that you have a choice of which you use from one script to the next?

***The question:***

Does it work to install Tensorflow and Pytorch in the same environment, be it base or a new one for the project / important package / purpose / whatever?